# Diferencias entre "Sánguche" y "Sandwich", y origen de la palabra

Tags: uso-de-palabras, diferencias-regionales, significado

Quiero saber si comerse un **sánguche** es lo mismo que si comiera un **sandwich**, y si no lo es quisiera una descripción básica.

La palabra *sánguche* parece ser un anglicismo de *sándwich*, y quisiera saber el origen de esta última.

Al sur de las islas Malvinas hay unas islas llamadas *Sandwich del Sur*, ¿Será de ahí el origen?

Comment: Nosotros los cubanos decimos tengo ganas de comerme un pan con pollo, biste, jamón y más. Casi nunca decimos saguiche. Eso de sándwich es de los norteamericanos.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

En el diccionario panhispánico de dudas se puede consultar lo siguiente en la entrada para "[sándwich](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=s%C3%A1ndwich)":

> [Sándwich] es la forma mayoritariamente usada por los hablantes cultos en todo el ámbito hispánico, aunque en algunos países americanos, especialmente en Colombia, Venezuela, Chile y el Perú, circulan adaptaciones como *sánduche* o *sánguche*, más propias de registros coloquiales y desaconsejadas en favor de la unidad.

Así que, efectivamente, ambas palabras parecen significar lo mismo, salvo que algún autóctono nos informe de lo contrario (ignoro si habrá sutiles diferencias).

Sobre el origen, parece estar documentada la [siguiente historia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1ndwich):

> El sándwich posee una historia que establece sus orígenes en el siglo XVIII, a partir del aristócrata inglés John Montagu, IV conde de Sandwich (1718-1792), aunque no fue él su inventor. Se dice de este conde que le gustaba comer de esta forma porque así podía jugar a las cartas mientras comía, sin ensuciarse los dedos. En 1762, Montagu estuvo veinticuatro horas seguidas ante una mesa de juego. Para calmar el hambre, pidió un poco de carne entre dos rebanadas de pan. A este nuevo tentempié se le puso el nombre de sándwich, en honor al conde.

Comment: @ArtEze efectivamente, la aplicación móvil de Stack Exchange funciona bastante bien.

Comment: Y, efectivamente, las islas se llaman así [en honor de ese mismo personaje](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorio_brit%C3%A1nico_de_ultramar_de_las_Islas_Georgias_del_Sur_y_Sandwich_del_Sur#Islas_Sandwich_del_Sur).

Comment: @JMVanPelt entendí la pregunta al revés, como que si los sándwiches se llaman así por las islas, por eso no mencioné el tema en la respuesta. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Estás en lo cierto, y, en efecto, el nombre de los sandwiches no viene del de las islas, que es lo que se preguntaba; pero, ya que ambas denominaciones se refieren a la misma persona, valía la pena comentarlo como curiosidad.

Answer (score -1):

"Sánguche" o "sanguchito" es del lunfardo argentino.

Comment: Ya me respondieron, gracias. ¿Podrías editar la respuesta explicando por qué se considera lunfardo y de dónde obtuviste esa información?